# how to iterate through cells in MIN/MAX function in VB excel 2003?

Tags: excel, iteration, minmax, vba

```
    Set min=min1=1000, max=max1=position=0   
    For i=2 to 10 do 
    min=**MIN(A(i,j):A(i+5,j));**  
    if position=0 then min1=min, position=1 else  
    For j=2 to 10 do  {max=**MAX(A(i,j):A(i+5,j));**  
    if max<min then next j else position=0, next i
```

I am new at this and trying to do next code above in VB excel(problem is bolded):Thanks

Comment: you cannot bold in the code. Plus, you tried to bold several lines. Plus, this doesn't look like Excel VBA. Plus, tell us what doesn't work. Plus, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 7):

It is impossible to correct all your code because it is not clear what you are trying to do.  But the following might give you a start.

It is always best to declare your variables and to specify their type:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim max As Integer
Dim max1 As Integer
Dim min As Integer
Dim min1 As Integer
Dim Position As Integer
```

I prefer to declare them in alphabetic order but that is not a requirement.

You need:

```
  min = 1000
  min1 = 1000
  max = 0
  max1 = 0
  Position = 0
```

There are the following mistakes in `Set min=min1=1000, max=max1=position=0`:

- Set is only used for objects.
- You cannot separate statements by commas.
- In some languages `min=min1=1000` means `min1=1000, min=min1` but in VBA it means:

  ```
  If min1=1000 Then
    min=True
  Else
    min=False
  End if
  ```

There is no `Do` at the end of a For statement.  So:

```
    For i = 2 To 10
```

MIN and MAX are worksheet functions.  To use then in VBA you have to say they are worksheet functions.  There are no semicolons at the end of statements in VBA.  You have used j in the MIN function but have not set its value yet.

I cannot tell the location of the values that are parameters to MIN and MAX.

If the location is in the current worksheet you need something like:

```
With ActiveSheet
  min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(.Range("B16:F16"))
End With
```

or perhaps like:

```
With ActiveSheet
  min = Application.WorksheetFunction.min(.Range(.Cells(i,j),.Cells(i+5,j)))
End With
```

It is possible, to use the MIN and MAX functions on an array but I know of no way of selecting a portion of an array.

Hope this gives you a start.

Comment: sorry for beeing so ambiguous, JMax is right.  Mainly, my question is how to move through a column in the loop for 1 place to do min/max function for n places. Basicly, i need to do MIN(A1:An), MIN(A2:An+1), MIN(A3:An+2)...,n is variable. You are telling me that you don't know the way of selecting a portion of an array, so there is no way doing this for n that is not fixed, i.e. for variable portion of an array? and thank you so much for your answer above :)

Comment: In your original question you seem to be accessing an array with two dimensions. What I said was I do not believe you can apply MIN and MAX to a range within an array. If you are accessing a worksheet, you can specify a range of any size. Look at my last block of code. `Cells(i,j)` identifies the start of range. `Cells(i+5,j)` identifies the end of range. Within Cells, the first parameter is the row and the second the column. If you do want to access a range within an array, there are other techniques that will allow this. Explain what you want more clearly and perhaps you can have it.

Comment: I am not into games or game theory so I had to look MinMax up. If you do not know VBA why are you using it for tree searches? If you want to learn VB, I would suggest Microsoft VB 2010 Express. It is not relevant for you but the learning curve from VBA is minimal. The Express version is single user but is free. Other versions have a free-trial period. VB 2010 is blindingly fast compared with VBA and comes with thousands of functions including tree building and searching. An alternative is C# 2010 Express which is also free.  It has more features at the price of being more difficult to learn.